# OneDrive SDK - IOS Get Special Folder

Tags: ios, onedrive

I am confused to the correct usage of the OneDriveSDK for IOS on the correct way to create a query in order to get all items in the special folder.

I want to get the music items  but once I create the request how should it be executed ?

There is no relevant example I can find anywhere. Other types of requests have implementation methods, but not special folders

The url I want to construct is simple enough

```
https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/special/music/children
```

But I am confused on how to use the SDK to create and execute it

```
@class ODItemRequest, ODURLSessionDataTask;
```

The furthest I got was

```
ODSpecialCollectionRequest *musicCollectionRequest = self.client.drive.special.request;
```

What would I do next ?

documentation is at

https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-ios/blob/master/docs/overview.md

and the sdk is at

https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-i

```
ODSpecialCollectionRequest.h

#import "ODModels.h"
#import "ODCollectionRequest.h"

typedef void (^ODItemCompletionHandler)(ODItem *response, NSError *error);

typedef void (^ODSpecialCompletionHandler)(ODCollection *response, ODSpecialCollectionRequest *nextRequest, NSError *error);

/**
* The header for type ODSpecialCollectionRequestBuilder.
*/



@interface ODSpecialCollectionRequest : ODCollectionRequest
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First notice that the request you are generating isn't quite right.  You want an `ODChildrenCollectionRequest`, generated from the "Music" folder.  To do this you will need to construct the correct URL using method calls (not properties like you have above).  This looks like:

```
ODChildrenCollectionRequest *request = [[self.client drive] special:@"Music"] children] request];
```

You then want to execute a get on the children request.  This looks like :

```
[request getWithCompletion:^(ODCollection *response, ODChildrenCollectionRequest *nextRequest, NSError *error){
     if(!error){
     // Do Stuff with children
     }
}];
```

The completion handler takes three parameters

1. the `ODCollection` which contains a `NSArray` of `ODItem` called
   `values` these are the children of the music folder.
2. Another `ODChildrenCollectionRequest`, By default we only return the first
       200 items in a collection, this is another request you can issue
       that will return the next page of items.
3. An `NSError` object, this will be `nil` unless there was an error
       somewhere along the request.

Comment: @Ace Thank for the quick answer, my confusion was I thought I needed to create a ODSpecialCollectionRequest

Comment: There is an additional issue/bug it seems to access the special folders I need to assign a onedrive.readwrite scope onedrive.readonly gives me a 403. Is this by design ?

Comment: What's happening is we're currently returning a 403 when trying to access a special folder that doesn't exist using a readonly scope. This is a bug, we should be returning a 404, but the fix hasn't made it out yet (it was out but we had to revert due to another issue). Here's the relevant issue link: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/110.

Comment: Not quite the same, I was accessing folders which did exist. The read/write scope will do for now